# not able to parse XML string with logstash grok filter

Tags: xml, elasticsearch, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I am trying to parse the XML string data usign Grok but looks like I am doing something wrong, please help me on this.

**XML String Data :**

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><a><expirationDate xmlns=\"http://epcis.abc.com/extension\">2019-05-15</expirationDate><lotNumber xmlns=\"http://epcis.abc.com/extension\">LOT-1047</lotNumber><productionDate xmlns=\"http://epcis.abc.com/extension\">10/10/2016 10:25:57</productionDate><quantity1 xmlns=\"http://epcis.abc.com/extension\">1,047</quantity1><EXT1 xmlns=\"http://epcis.abc.com/extension\">EXT1</EXT1><EXT2 xmlns=\"http://epcis.abc.com/extension\">EXT2</EXT2><EXT3 xmlns=\"http://epcis.abc.com/extension\">EXT3</EXT3><EXT4 xmlns=\"http://epcis.abc.com/extension\">EXT4</EXT4><EXT5 xmlns=\"http://epcis.abc.com/extension\">EXT5</EXT5><EXT6 xmlns=\"http://epcis.abc.com/extension\">EXT6</EXT6><EXT7 xmlns=\"http://epcis.abc.com/extension\">EXT7</EXT7><EXT8 xmlns=\"http://epcis.abc.com/extension\">EXT8</EXT8><EXT9 xmlns=\"http://epcis.abc.com/extension\">EXT9</EXT9><EXT10 xmlns=\"http://epcis.abc.com/extension\">EXT10</EXT10><EXT11 xmlns=\"http://epcis.abc.com/extension\">EXT11</EXT11><EXT12 xmlns=\"http://epcis.abc.com/extension\">EXT12</EXT12><EXT13 xmlns=\"http://epcis.abc.com/extension\"><EXT xmlns=\"http://epcis.abc.com\">EXT13</EXT></EXT13><EXT14 xmlns=\"http://epcis.abc.com/extension\"><EXT xmlns=\"http://epcis.abc.com\">EXT14</EXT></EXT14><EXT15 xmlns=\"http://epcis.abc.com/extension\"><EXT xmlns=\"http://epcis.abc.com\">EXT15</EXT></EXT15><EXT16 xmlns=\"http://epcis.abc.com/extension\"><EXT xmlns=\"http://epcis.abc.com\">EXT16</EXT></EXT16></a>
```

**filter**

```
  input {
        jdbc {
            jdbc_validate_connection => true
            jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost.:1521/orcl"
            jdbc_user => "abc"
            jdbc_password => "abc"
            jdbc_driver_library => "/home/user/ES/ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.0.jar"
            jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        statement => "SELECT to_clob(ilmd), event_parent_epc_sn, event_ext_raw FROM event"
        }
    }
    filter {
   xml {
    source => "event_ext_raw"
    target => "parsed"
  }
  split {
    field => "[parsed][a]"
    add_field => {expirationDate => "%{[parsed][a][expirationDate]}"}
  }
}
    output   {
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    }
```

**Error Message :**

> Exception in pipelineworker, the pipeline stopped processing new
>   events, please check your filter configuration and restart Logstash.
>   {"exception"=>#,
>   "backtrace"=>["/home/user/ES/logstash-2.2.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-split-2.0.2/lib/logstash/filters/split.rb:46:in
>   `filter'",
>   "/home/user/ES/logstash-2.2.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.2.0-java/lib/logstash/filters/base.rb:151:in`
>   multi_filter'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'",
>   "/home/user/ES/logstash-2.2.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.2.0-java/lib/logstash/filters/base.rb:148:in`
>   multi_filter'", "(eval):67:in `filter_func'",
>   "/home/user/ES/logstash-2.2.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.2.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:241:in`
>   filter_batch'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'",
>   "org/jruby/RubyEnumerable.java:852:in`inject'",
>   "/home/user/ES/logstash-2.2.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.2.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:239:in
>   `filter_batch'",
>   "/home/user/ES/logstash-2.2.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.2.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:197:in`
>   worker_loop'",
>   "/home/user/ES/logstash-2.2.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.2.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:175:in
>   `start_workers'"], :level=>:error} LogStash::ConfigurationError: Only
>   String and Array types are splittable. field:[parsed][a] is of type =
>   NilClass

Comment: are you using the `xml` plugin as well? If you could show the whole filter criteria so that we could reproduce?

Comment: Sure, let me edit the question.

Comment: My data looks like XML but it is String of XML so I am not able to break it in array hence split is not working.

Comment: So even doing this: match => {"message" , "event_sub_id"} doesn't work? You getting any errors?

Comment: yes, let me send you the error

Comment: It says : field:[parsed][a] is of type = NilClass

Comment: Are you sure both the fields you're trying to split do exist? [ref](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/bug-with-split-filter-and-xml/65107)

Comment: I got the output :)

Comment: grok {
 match => {
  "event_ext_raw" => "<expirationDate xmlns=\"http://epcis.mycomp.com/extension\">%{GREEDYDATA:expirationDate}</expirationDate><lotNumber xmlns=\"http://epcis.mycomp.com/extension\">%{DATA:lotNumber}</lotNumber>"
 }
   }

Comment: The change was to add the escape character for strings?

Comment: Can you tell me how to insert these two outputs in an array, something like this :  ilmd : [
  "expirationDate":  "2017-08-06",
  "lotNumber":  "OT-400"
]

Comment: Currently the output is like this : {
  "expirationDate":  "2017-08-06",
  "lotNumber":  "OT-400"
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129437/discussion-between-kulasangar-and-shamim-ahmad).